# Gaming laptop with 16GB RAM for around €1500?

Tags: laptop, gaming, memory

I would like to buy laptop which is good for playing modern games (of 2015, and for 2016 which are coming), multitasking (video editing and internet usage) and excellent for multimedia (HD videos watching and HD audio listening).

It should have at least a core i7 processor (at least 3GHz) with 16GB RAM and graphics card with at least of 2GB DDR5 memory.

Must have WiFi and Bluetooth and at least one USB 3.0 port and one USB 2.0 (because I have one external USB 3.0 HDD and one USB 2.0 HDD).

Which one would you recommend me to buy? I have a budget of around €1500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this laptop would match your needs, doesn't it?

[Asus ROG G501VW-FY031T PC Portable Gamer 15.6" Full HD](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B019H4B2Z6/ref=cm_sw_r_other_awd_nRt2wbMMV80H4) (sorry, it's a link to the French amazon website, but I'm sure you'll find it easily on whatever your country is)

It features :

- A core i7 processor (With "only" 2.6 Ghz of frequency, but I'm not sure it will make a difference in the games).
- 16 Gb RAM
- 128 Gb SSD for the OS, and 1Tb HDD for the storage.
- A GeForce GTX960M graphics card with 4Gb RAM (And, according to my researches, [is equipped with DDR5](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Nvidia-GeForce-GTX-960M-Review.137893.0.html))
- Equipped with wifi and bluetooth
- 3 USB3 ports (and no USB2 port)

I'm wondering about your question for USB 2.0,though. Isn't USB 3 meant to be retro compatible?

As for the processor frequency, I don't think it will make a difference in a gaming configuration (The graphics card makes the difference and is not limited by the frequency of the processor).

I don't know if it can make a slight difference for video editing. [After some researches](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1736257/gpu-cpu-video-editing.html), that's the number of cores of your processor (The one in this configuration has 4) that could matter, depending on your software, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for laptop for gaming you should look for machine with best GPU. On newegg in this price range the best solution will be:

**[ASUS ROG G751JY-WH71](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834232849)** $1600 most important features:

- i7 4th generation CPU
- GeForce GTX 980M
- SSD 128 GB
- 16 GB DDR3 RAM

In your price range it will be best solution because of GTX 980M GPU. It is the most important part for gaming in laptops. The rest will also meet your requirements. It has no USB 2.0 port but USB 3.0 is backward compatible so you can use one of USB 3.0 slots for USB 2.0 devices.

---

If you are from Croatia like your profile says, it will be a little harder. I checked that €1500 is around 11500 Kn so I looked for laptop which meets your requirements in Croatian shops (I'm not familiar with Croatian market it would be easier if you provide some "good croatian shops url's") and I found:

**[Acer ASPIRE G9-591-73PJ Predator 15](http://www.ekupi.hr/Notebook-Acer-ASPIRE-G9-591-73PJ-Predator-15-NXQ07EX011-801899.aspx)** - 11000 Kn on ekupi.hr:

Pros:

- 6th generation i7 CPU (6700HQ)
- 8 GB RAM DDR4 (it is enough for gaming)
- GeForce GTX970M (worse than ASUS but should be enough for most of new games)

Cons:

- no SSD drive
- no operating system

It is much worse than ASUS but it's best solution which I could find on Croatian websites. I would look for something with GTX 980M if it's possible in this price range in Croatia. If you provide me with url's of "good" Croatian shops with laptops I will look what you can find there.